# Помогите вывести микроразметку (scheme.org) для рейтинга

Tags: javascript, php, schema.org, microdata, ratingbar

Поставил плагин https://ratekit.com/

Все отлично работает. Но не знаю как вывести рейтинг в микроразметку.

В отзывах на этот плагин парень как ты вывел рейтинг, но не написал как. Говорит, что прописал пару строчек кода.

Подскажите, что нужно сделать, что бы гугл увидел рейтинг.

Comment: Тот парень, судя по всему, просто отпечатал всю нужную ему html-разметку как обычно вообще без этого плагина

Comment: Я думал об этом, что он так сделал. А можно как то вывести, что бы работало непосредственно с этим рейтингом?

Comment: Судя по тому, что там написано «RateKit saves ratings in PHP's tiny built-in database SQLite», у вас не должно вызвать больших затруднений найти и прочитать этот самый sqlite-файл в php-коде и вывести что вам нужно — это, видимо, и сделал тот парень

Comment: А не подскажите, как можно это вывести? Я просто реально дуб в этом деле. Просто уже часа 4 пытаюсь в этом разобраться. Буду очень благодарен Вам за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте для оборачивающего тега атрибуты `itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating"`, для тега с оценкой `itemprop="ratingValue"`, а для тега с количеством проголосовавших `itemprop="reviewCount"`. Это один из вариантов, если значение скрыто, то можете использовать тег `meta`, или например можете если используете дописать в json согласно [документации](https://schema.org/Rating).

```html
<div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
  Рейтинг:
  <span itemprop="ratingValue">4.5</span> из 5
  <span itemprop="reviewCount">11</span> человек проголосовало
</div>
```